# Why MyBatis can't map the JSONB type to a Map<String, Object> or to JsonNode?

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, mybatis

I have a `DTO` as:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class UserHasAssetDTO {

    private Integer id;

    ...

    private Map<String, Object> props;
}
```

and a `Repository` where I have the method:

```
@Select("select id, ..., props from bla bla bla")
List<UserHasAssetDTO> getALLAssetsFilteredByDate(@Param("username") String username, @Param("startDate") String startDate, @Param("endDate") String endDate);
```

Note: the field props in my PostgreSQL DB is `JSONB` type.

If I execute the query manually, I can see that the props are populated correctly.

But, when in my service:

```
    public List<UserHasAssetDTO> userHasALLAssets(String user, String start, String end) {

        List<UserHasAssetDTO> userHasAssetDTOList = userHasAssetRepository.getALLAssetsFilteredByDate(user, start, end);

        log.info("userHasALLAssets: {}", userHasAssetDTOList);

        return userHasAssetDTOList;
    }
```

The props fields ar `null`!!!

I suspect that I am not mapping PostgreSQL's `JSONB` type correctly on my DTO.

How can I fix it so that the props fields are populated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this Class:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes({JdbcType.JAVA_OBJECT})
@MappedTypes({JsonNode.class})
public class JsonNodeTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<JsonNode> {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, JsonNode parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
        jsonObject.setType("jsonb");
        try {
            jsonObject.setValue(parameter.toString());
            ps.setObject(i, jsonObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        String jsonSource = rs.getString(columnName);
        if (jsonSource != null) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readTree(jsonSource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String jsonSource = rs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (jsonSource != null) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readTree(jsonSource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String jsonSource = cs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (jsonSource != null) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readTree(jsonSource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and `JsonNode` type in my DTO.